# Is the Snowflake query_id (system derived) unique to the text of a SQL query (like the SQL_ID in Oracle is)? or is it unique to the query execution?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is the Snowflake query_id (system derived) unique to the text of a SQL query (like the SQL_ID in Oracle is)?   or is it unique to the query execution?

Answer (score 0):

It is unique to that instance of the query being executed

Answer (score 0):

The `query_id` is unqiue per each run:

```
SELECT * FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.CUSTOMER;
SELECT LAST_QUERY_ID();

SELECT * FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.CUSTOMER;
SELECT LAST_QUERY_ID();

SELECT * FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.CUSTOMER;
SELECT LAST_QUERY_ID();
```

Same query text, different query ids, which could be also checked in [QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY())
ORDER BY START_TIME DESC;
```